# Calculation of simple elasticity problem

Tags: macroeconomics, elasticity

I'm reading Advanced Macroeconomics by Romer and having trouble to understand very simple calculation provided in just one sentence.

Define real money market equilibrium condition as $(\frac{M}{P})^s=L(Y,i)=(\frac{M}{P})^d$
Then the price leve is $P=\frac{M}{L(Y,i)}$
If the interest elasticity of money demand is $-0.2$, we need almost $32$ times rise in interest rate to increase price level double.

I can't understand where "$32$ times" comes from.
From the definition of elasticity, and using the fact that
if we want to make price level double then $L(Y,i)$ should be reduced by half,
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial i}\frac{i}{L}=\frac{\partial L}{L}\frac{i}{\partial i}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{i}{\partial i}=-0.2$ then $\frac{\partial i}{i}=2.3$
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi! Where did the $-1/2$ come from in your equation $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial i}\frac{i}{L}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial i}\frac{i}{\partial i}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{i}{\partial i}=-0.2$$? Also, it seems like in this case we would have $\frac{\partial i}{i} = 2.5$? It feels like you are only sharing half of your thoughts with us.

Comment: @Giskard I edited my post to prove why $\frac{\partial L}{L}=-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Can you please tell us a bit about your background, so that someone can answer in an understandable way? Are you familiar with differentials and calculus?

Answer (score 2):

If $L(Y,i)$ has a constant elasticity of $-0.2$ then you can write it as:
$$
L(Y,i) = g(Y)i^{-0.2}.
$$
Then for the period 0 and period 1 price levels you have:
$$
P_0 = \frac{M}{g(Y)i_0^{-0.2}} \text{ and } P_1 = \frac{M}{g(Y)i_1^{-0.2}}.
$$
We have that $P_1 = 2 P_0$ so:
$$
2 \frac{M}{g(y) i_0^{-0.2}} = \frac{M}{g(Y)i_1^{-0.2}}.
$$
Simplifying gives:
$$
2 i_1^{-0.2} = i_0^{-0.2}.
$$
This gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{i_1}{i_0} = 2^5 = 32
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Hi @tdm. For my own benefit, could you include any additional steps in going from: $$2i_1^{-0.2} = i_0^{-0.2}$$ to $$\frac{i_1}{i_0} = 2^5$$.  Would be appreciated.

Comment: @ EB3112 It is enough to understand that $0.2=\frac{1}{5}$.